# Lambda expression to return one result for each distinct value in list

Tags: c#, linq, list, lambda

I currently have a large list of a class object and I am currently using the following lambda function to return elements that meet the condition.

```
var call = callList.Where(i => i.ApplicationID == 001).ToList();
```

This will return a list of objects that all have an id of 001.

I am now curious as to what different ApplicationIDs there are. So I would like a lambda function that will look into this list and return a list where all the element have a different ApplicationID but only fetches one of those.

Comment: there is a range but i do not know the maximum range

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If i understand your question you can try:

```
var list = callList.GroupBy(x => x.ApplicationID).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
```

So if you have a list like:

```
AppID:1, AppID:1, AppID:2, AppID:2, AppID:3, AppID:3
```

Will return:

```
AppID:1 AppID:2 AppID:3
```

Comment: At least you seem to have a plausible answer to the question

Comment: @Steve It was a bit hard to understand at first (at least for me).

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria Nice answer. And yeah, OP's question title is misleading, I edited it a little

Comment: Thanks that solved it, and thanks for changing the title too :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use either First or FirstOrDefault to get back one result

```
var call = callList.First(i => i.ApplicationID == 001);
```

If no call exisrs with an ApplicationID of 001 this will throw an exception. If this may be expected consider using:

```
var call = callList.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ApplicationID == 001);
```

Here null will be returned if no such call exists and you can handle accordingly in you code.

To find out what other ApplicationId's exist you can query:

```
var Ids = callList.Where(i => i.ApplicationID != 001).Select(i => i.ApplicationID).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to use the `Distinct` in the query, but it makes you take care about the values equality. Let's assume your type is called CallClass and try:

```
class CallClass : IEqualityComparer<CallClass>
{

    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }

    //other properties etc.

    public bool Equals(CallClass x, CallClass y)
    {
        return x.ApplicationId == y.ApplicationId;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(CallClass obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Now you're able to query values distinctly:

```
var call = callList.Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are saying

> I am now curious as to what different ApplicationIDs there are. So I
>   would like a lambda function that will look into this list and return
>   a list where all the element have a different ApplicationID but only
>   fetches one of those.

I would suggest that is never something you'd actually want. You either *don't care* about the elements, you care about *all* of them, or you care about a *specific* one. There are few (none?) situations where you care about a random one from the list.

Without knowing about which specific one you care, I can't give you a solution for that version. Allesandro has given you a solution for the random one.

When you *only* care about the distinct ID's you would end up with

```
callList.Select(c => c.ApplicationID).Distinct()
```

which just gives you all ApplicationIDs.

if you care about *all* of them, you'd end up with

```
callList.GroupBy(c => c.ApplicationID)
```

this will give you an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<String, Thingy>>` (where Thingy is the type of whatever the type of elements of callList is.)

This means you now have a collection of `ApplicationID -> collection of Thingy's`. For each distinct ApplicationID you'll have a "List" (actually `IEnumerable`) of every element that has that ApplicationID

If you care for the `Thingy` of that - for example - has the lowest value of property Foo you would want

```
callList.GroupBy(c => c.ApplicationID)
        .Select(group => group.OrderBy(thingy => thingy.Foo).First()))
```

here you first *Group* them by ApplicationID, and then for each list of thingies with the sample ApplicationID you *Select* the first one of them if you *Order* them by `Foo`